# Moving through node field point to point coding in C

Tags: c, pointers, switch-statement

In the process of making a program that moves through a node field from point X to point Y. I am new to C and I'm having issues with errors in my code. I'm asking for your help to fix these  (most likely stupid errors) so i can hopefully get this to run properly. ANY advice would be greatly appreciated!

**here's the node field**
http://i1350.photobucket.com/albums/p771/Clarkyy4/Untitled_zps9bbda929.png

**exact problem given to solve** 
Project:  Find the shortest network path between any two nodes in the network. 
*Enter a source node in the above network.
*Enter a destination node in the network.
* Find the shortest path from source to destination and display it.
i.e.  Enter source node: E
Enter source node: H
Shortest path: E - F – G – H   (3 hops) 
 (There may be more than one shortest path, find at least one)
You must use one of the ADTs we have discussed in class (I suggest, either queuesADT or linkListADT).

**here is the linkListADT.h**

```
/*  This header file contains the functions to maintain
and process a linked list.
   Written by:
   Date:
*/

//#include "P5-01.h"        /* Singly-Linked List ADT Type Definitions */
//  List ADT Type Defintions 
typedef struct node 
   {
    void*        dataPtr;
    struct node* link;
   } NODE; 

typedef struct
   {
    int   count; 
    NODE* pos;
    NODE* head; 
    NODE* rear;
    int    (*compare) (void* argu1, void* argu2); 
   } LIST;

//#include "P5-02.h"        /* List ADT Prototype Declarations */
//  Prototype Declarations 
LIST* createList   (int (*compare)
                   (void* argu1, void* argu2));
LIST* destroyList  (LIST* list);

int   addNode   (LIST* pList, void* dataInPtr);

bool  removeNode   (LIST*  pList,
                    void*  keyPtr,
                    void** dataOutPtr);

bool  searchList   (LIST*  pList,
                    void*  pArgu,
                    void** pDataOut);

bool  retrieveNode (LIST*  pList,
                    void*  pArgu,
                    void** dataOutPtr);

bool  traverse     (LIST*  pList,
                    int    fromWhere,
                    void** dataOutPtr);

int   listCount    (LIST*  pList);
bool  emptyList    (LIST*  pList);
bool  fullList     (LIST*  pList); 

static bool _insert1   (LIST* pList,
                      NODE* pPre,
                      void* dataInPtr);

static void _delete  (LIST*  pList,
                      NODE*  pPre,
                      NODE*  pLoc,
                      void** dataOutPtr);
static bool _search  (LIST*  pList,
                      NODE** pPre,
                      NODE** pLoc,
                      void*  pArgu);
    //  End of List ADT Definitions 

    //#include "P5-03.h"        /* Create linked list */
    /*  =============== createList ==============
Allocates dynamic memory for a list head
node and returns its address to caller
   Pre    compare is address of compare function 
          used to compare two nodes.
   Post   head has allocated or error returned
   Return head node pointer or null if overflow 
    */
    LIST* createList 
     (int (*compare) (void* argu1, void* argu2))
    {
    //  Local Definitions 
LIST* list;

    //  Statements 
list = (LIST*) malloc (sizeof (LIST));
if (list)
   {
    list->head    = NULL;
    list->pos     = NULL;
    list->rear    = NULL;
    list->count   = 0;
    list->compare = compare;
   } // if 

return list;
}   // createList 

//#include "P5-04.h"        /* Add Node */
/*  ================== addNode =================
Inserts data into list.
   Pre    pList is pointer to valid list
          dataInPtr pointer to insertion data
   Post   data inserted or error
   Return -1 if overflow
           0 if successful
           1 if dupe key
*/
int addNode (LIST* pList, void* dataInPtr)
{
//  Local Definitions 
bool found;
bool success;

NODE* pPre;
NODE* pLoc;

//  Statements 
found = _search (pList, &pPre, &pLoc, dataInPtr);
if (found)
   // Duplicate keys not allowed 
   return (+1);

success = _insert1 (pList, pPre, dataInPtr);
if (!success)
   // Overflow 
   return (-1);
return (0);
}   // addNode 

//#include "P5-05.h"        /* Insert Node */
/*  =================== _insert1 ================== 
Inserts data pointer into a new node.
   Pre    pList pointer to a valid list 
          pPre  pointer to data's predecessor 
          dataInPtr data pointer to be inserted 
   Post   data have been inserted in sequence 
   Return boolean, true  if successful, 
                   false if memory overflow 
*/
static bool _insert1 (LIST* pList, NODE* pPre,
                 void* dataInPtr)
{
//  Local Definitions 
NODE* pNew;

//  Statements 
if (!(pNew = (NODE*) malloc(sizeof(NODE))))
   return false;

pNew->dataPtr   = dataInPtr; 
pNew->link      = NULL; 

if (pPre == NULL)
   {
    // Adding before first node or to empty list. 
    pNew->link       = pList->head;
    pList->head      = pNew;
    if (pList->count == 0)
       // Adding to empty list. Set rear 
       pList->rear = pNew;
   } // if pPre 
else
   {
    // Adding in middle or at end 
    pNew->link  = pPre->link;
    pPre->link  = pNew;

    // Now check for add at end of list 
    if (pNew->link     == NULL)
         pList->rear   =  pNew;
   } // if else 

(pList->count)++;
return true;
}   // _insert1 

//#include "P5-06.h"        /* Remove Node */
/*  ================= removeNode ================ 
Removes data from list. 
   Pre    pList pointer to a valid list
          keyPtr pointer to key to be deleted
          dataOutPtr pointer to data pointer
   Post   Node deleted or error returned.
   Return false not found; true deleted
*/
bool removeNode  (LIST*  pList, void*  keyPtr,
              void** dataOutPtr)
{
//  Local Definitions 
bool found;

NODE* pPre;
NODE* pLoc;

//  Statements 
found = _search (pList, &pPre, &pLoc, keyPtr);
if (found)
   _delete (pList, pPre, pLoc, dataOutPtr);

return found;
}   // removeNode 

//#include "P5-07.h"        /* Delete Node */
/*  ================= _delete ================ 
Deletes data from a list and returns 
pointer to data to calling module.
   Pre    pList pointer to valid list.
          pPre  pointer to predecessor node
          pLoc  pointer to target node
          dataOutPtr pointer to data pointer
   Post   Data have been deleted and returned 
          Data memory has been freed
*/
void _delete (LIST* pList, NODE*  pPre,
          NODE* pLoc,  void** dataOutPtr)
{
//  Statements 
*dataOutPtr = pLoc->dataPtr;
if (pPre == NULL)
   // Deleting first node 
   pList->head = pLoc->link;
else
   // Deleting any other node 
   pPre->link = pLoc->link;

// Test for deleting last node 
if (pLoc->link == NULL)
    pList->rear = pPre;

(pList->count)--;
free (pLoc);

return;
}   // _delete 

//#include "P5-08.h"        /* Search Interface */
/*  ================== searchList ================= 
Interface to search function. 
   Pre    pList pointer to initialized list.
          pArgu pointer to key being sought
   Post   pDataOut contains pointer to found data
     -or- NULL if not found
   Return boolean true successful; false not found 
*/
bool searchList (LIST*  pList, void* pArgu,
             void** pDataOut)
{
//  Local Definitions 
bool  found;

NODE* pPre;
NODE* pLoc;

//  Statements 
found = _search (pList, &pPre, &pLoc, pArgu);
if (found)
    *pDataOut = pLoc->dataPtr;
else
    *pDataOut = NULL;
return found;
}   // searchList 

//#include "P5-09.h"        /* Search List */
/*  ================== _search =================
Searches list and passes back address of node 
containing target and its logical predecessor.
   Pre    pList pointer to initialized list 
          pPre  pointer variable to predecessor
          pLoc  pointer variable to receive node
          pArgu pointer to key being sought
   Post   pLoc points to first equal/greater key 
     -or- null if target > key of last node
          pPre points to largest node < key
     -or- null if target < key of first node
   Return boolean true found; false not found 

*/
bool _search (LIST*  pList, NODE** pPre,
          NODE** pLoc,  void*  pArgu)
{
//  Macro Definition 
#define COMPARE \
( ((* pList->compare) (pArgu, (*pLoc)->dataPtr)) )

#define COMPARE_LAST \
((* pList->compare) (pArgu, pList->rear->dataPtr))

//  Local Definitions 
int result;

//  Statements 
*pPre  = NULL;
*pLoc  = pList->head;
if (pList->count == 0)
    return false;

// Test for argument > last node in list 
if ( COMPARE_LAST > 0) 
   {
    *pPre = pList->rear;
    *pLoc = NULL;
    return false;
   } // if 

while ( (result = COMPARE) > 0 )
   {
    // Have not found search argument location 
    *pPre = *pLoc;
    *pLoc = (*pLoc)->link;
   } // while 

if (result == 0)
   // argument found--success 
   return true;
else
   return false;
}   // _search 

//#include "P5-10.h"        /* Retrieve Node */
/*  ================== retrieveNode ================ 
This algorithm retrieves data in the list without
changing the list contents. 
   Pre    pList pointer to initialized list.
          pArgu pointer to key to be retrieved
   Post   Data (pointer) passed back to caller
   Return boolean true success; false underflow
*/
static bool retrieveNode (LIST*  pList,
                      void*  pArgu, 
                      void** dataOutPtr)
{
//  Local Definitions 
bool  found;

NODE* pPre;
NODE* pLoc;

//  Statements 
found = _search (pList, &pPre, &pLoc, pArgu);
if (found)
   {
    *dataOutPtr = pLoc->dataPtr;
    return true;
   } // if 

*dataOutPtr = NULL;
return false;
}   // retrieveNode 

//#include "P5-11.h"        /* Empty List */
/*  ================= emptyList ================
Returns boolean indicating whether or not the
list is empty
   Pre    pList is a pointer to a valid list 
   Return boolean true empty; false list has data 
*/
bool emptyList (LIST* pList) 
{
//  Statements 
return (pList->count == 0);
}   // emptyList 

//#include "P5-12.h"        /* Full List */
/*  ================== fullList =================
Returns boolean indicating no room for more data.
This list is full if memory cannot be allocated for
another node. 
   Pre    pList pointer to valid list 
   Return boolean true if full
                  false if room for node 
*/
bool fullList (LIST* pList) 
{
//  Local Definitions 
NODE* temp;

//  Statements 
if ((temp = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(*(pList->head)))))
   {
    free (temp);
    return false;
   } // if 

// Dynamic memory full 
return true;

}   // fullList 

//#include "P5-13.h"        /* List Count */
/*  ================== listCount ==================
Returns number of nodes in list.
   Pre    pList is a pointer to a valid list
   Return count for number of nodes in list
*/
int listCount(LIST* pList) 
{
//  Statements 

return pList->count; 

}   // listCount 

//#include "P5-14.h"        /* Traverse List */
/*  ================== traverse =================
Traverses a list. Each call either starts at the
beginning of list or returns the location of the 
next element in the list.
   Pre    pList       pointer to a valid list
          fromWhere   0 to start at first element
          dataPtrOut  address of pointer to data
   Post   if more data, address of next node 
   Return true node located; false if end of list
*/
bool traverse (LIST*  pList,
          int    fromWhere,
          void** dataPtrOut)
{
//  Statements 
if (pList->count == 0)
    return false;

if (fromWhere == 0)
   {
     //Start from first node 
    pList->pos  = pList->head;
    *dataPtrOut = pList->pos->dataPtr;
    return true;
   } // if fromwhere 
else
   {
    // Start from current position 
    if (pList->pos->link == NULL)
        return false;
    else
       {
        pList->pos  = pList->pos->link;
        *dataPtrOut = pList->pos->dataPtr;
        return true;
       } // if else 
   } // if fromwhere else 
}   // traverse 

//#include "P5-15.h"        /* Destroy List */
/*  ================== destroyList =================
Deletes all data in list and recycles memory
   Pre    List is a pointer to a valid list.
   Post   All data and head structure deleted
   Return null head pointer
*/
LIST* destroyList (LIST* pList) 
{
//  Local Definitions 
NODE* deletePtr;

//  Statements 
if (pList)
   {
    while (pList->count > 0) 
       {
        // First delete data 
        free (pList->head->dataPtr);

        // Now delete node 
        deletePtr    = pList->head;
        pList->head  = pList->head->link; 
        pList->count--;
        free (deletePtr); 
       } // while 
    free (pList);
   } // if 
return NULL;
}   // destroyList
```

**Main Code**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h> 
#include "linkListADT.h" 


typedef struct

  {
   void*        dataPtr;
   struct node* link;
  } NODE; 

typedef struct
  {
   int   count; 
   NODE* pos;
   NODE* head; 
   NODE* rear; 

} DATA;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
// empty list
node *head = NULL;
// create a temporary
node *temp;

temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node)); // allocate
// place info to first node
temp->data->head = 'A'; 
temp->data->pos = 1; 
temp->data->rear = NULL;
// get address of head
temp->next=head;
head = temp;

}

{

char cnode = 'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'; 
int next; 
int cnode;
printf(cnode);
switch(cnode); 

{ 
case 'A'; 
next = rand()%3; 
switch(next); 
{
case 0: cnode = 'E'; break; 
case 1: cnode = 'F'; break; 
case 2: cnode = 'B'; break; 
}
case 'B'; 
next = rand()%3; 
switch(next); 
{
case 0: cnode = 'A'; break; 
case 1: cnode = 'C'; break; 
case 2: cnode = 'D'; break; 
}
case 'C'; 
next = rand()%3; 
switch(next); 
{
case 0: cnode = 'B'; break; 
case 1: cnode = 'F'; break; 
case 2: cnode = 'G'; break;
}
case 'D'; 
next = rand()%3; 
switch(next) 
{
case 0: cnode = 'B'; break; 
case 1: cnode = 'G'; break; 
case 2: cnode = 'H'; break;
}
case 'E'; 
next = rand()%3; 
switch(next) 
{
case 0: cnode = 'B'; break; 
case 1: cnode = 'G'; break; 
case 2: cnode = 'H'; break;
}
case 'F'; 
next = rand()%6; 
switch(next) 
{
case 0: cnode = 'C'; break; 
case 1: cnode = 'G'; break; 
case 2: cnode = 'E'; break; 
case 3: cnode = 'A'; break; 
case 4: cnode = 'J'; break; 
case 5: cnode = 'K'; break; 
}
case 'G'; 
next = rand()%4; 
switch(next) 
{
case 0: cnode = 'D'; break; 
case 1: cnode = 'F'; break; 
case 2: cnode = 'H'; break;
case 3: cnode = 'C': break; 
} 
case 'H'; 
next = rand()%4; 
switch(next) 
{
case 0: cnode = 'D'; break; 
case 1: cnode = 'G'; break; 
case 2: cnode = 'L'; break;
case 3: cnode = 'K': break; 
} 
case 'I'; 
next = rand()%2; 
switch(next) 
{
case 0: cnode = 'E'; break; 
case 1: cnode = 'J'; break; 
} 
case 'J'; 
next = rand()%3; 
switch(next) 
{
case 0: cnode = 'F'; break; 
case 1: cnode = 'I'; break; 
case 2: cnode = 'K'; break;
} 
case 'K'; 
next = rand()%4; 
switch(next) 
{
case 0: cnode = 'H'; break; 
case 1: cnode = 'L'; break; 
case 2: cnode = 'F'; break;
case 3: cnode = 'J'; break; 
} 
case 'L'; 
next = rand()%2; 
switch(next) 
{
case 0: cnode = 'H'; break; 
case 1: cnode = 'K'; break; 
}
}
}
}
return 0; 
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting exactly? There are two _tmain functions in your code.

Comment: @Étienne starts with error: class "node" has no member "data" under the data...`temp->data->head = 'A'; 
    temp->data->pos = 1; 
    temp->data->rear = NULL;`

Comment: There are also errors under some of the "case" "next "switch" statements

Comment: remember C is case sensitive, so node != NODE

Comment: @AK4749 Where exactly dose that need to be fixed?

Comment: well, there are.... a LOT of errors in here. is this exactly one source file? how does it fit with the rest of your project? what is that linkListADT.h include up top? is that custom? did you write it? you have `case X;` with a semicolon instead of colon, outside of switch statements, etc. Is this your first programming language period? you are using Microsoft-specific features - _tmain, TCHAR, is there a reason you are not writing portable C?

Comment: I tried to give it a shot to fix the errors but it's just better to start over. If this is your first time, look into loops (for, *while*), arrays, and structs/pointers. Basically, you're going to want to give each node an array of nodes that it connects to, store how many nodes as another field, and finally its name or position as a char. That should give you the structure of your node field. Then, using a loop, randomly choose a number 0 to NumConnectedNodes, and "walk" that pointer to go to the next node until your position is the character you want.

Comment: i can come back to this tomorrow if you have more questions

Comment: @AK4749 the project is basically to write a program using lists to get from any given node to any other given node. Yes the linkListADT.h is a custom file give to me by an instructor. I was advised to use it, I can include the file if you'd like. Yes this is my first class of Programing and first attempt in using switch statements. I was instructed to use switch statements.

Comment: @Ak4749 are there any parts of the program that I can use? This code took me most of the week to write. Starting completely over would take me past my deadline.

Comment: i think you had better include the assignment instructions and linkListADT.h both edited into this answer and have your code/question formatted nicely. it will greatly improve your chances of attracting more help from outside. Also look into ideone.com if the code is too long (you will have to paste linkListADT.h into the top of the same file because i don't think it can do includes). This will help others compile/test your code.

Comment: I didn't mean to say ALL the code is worthless, just that based on the limited amount of information, I really wasn't sure what you were trying to do. For example, you use switch statements correctly, but then incorrectly place a `case` label outside the switch. if we knew what exactly you were trying to do we can immediately help you out

Comment: @AK4749 Ive added everything you've asked for. Hopefully this will help you understand what i'm trying to accomplish exactly.If their is anything i missed i will be happy to edit

Comment: First: read here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem for the general problem space. Have you chosen an algorithm to implement? I'd suggest Djikstra's or A*. Both solve your problem directly. A* may or may not be a little more difficult to implement, but whichever is more intuitive for you, pick that one, then come back if you need some more help. I really don't see where your code can come into play here, your project doesn't even ask for user input for the traversal, just to get the initial and goal nodes. I'm sorry, much of your code won't be of much use. However, to speed

Comment: ...up the process, I'd suggest looking at Djikstra's Algorithm from the link I gave you and trying to write the pseudocode they have given you in C. it is explained VERY well. come back here with any questions and we'll be happy to help (hint: `The simplest implementation of the Dijkstra's algorithm stores vertices of set Q in an ordinary linked list or array, and extract minimum from Q is simply a linear search through all vertices in Q.`)

Answer (score 1):

The member's name in NODE is dataPtr, which is why you get the error: class "node" has no member "data"
What other errors do you get when compiling?